# add a new element to an array as a line break

Tags: php, arrays, element

How to set an element of an array as a line break?
For example:

```
$array(1,2,3,'\n');
```

I try to set the element as '\n' but It will print exactly '\n', not a line break when imploded.

```
implode('',$array);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes `"\n"` instead of `'\n'` single quotes, Single quotes treats as string

```
<?php
  $arr = [1,2,3,"\n","after line break"];
  echo implode('',$arr);
?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/865569

In your browser to add line break use `<br>` instead `\n`

Comment: for html line break you can use <br>

Comment: @user1844933: Yes you are right I forgot to add this, thanks